# Convert ListView to Line separated String Array and vice versa

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to take all items in my ListView and write each one into a new line inside a string Array (or something similar). This is so i can pass these values to a string property inside an object that is then saved to a SQL Database (Varchar(max)).

What i have tried sofar

```
public string ConvertToString(ListView l)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

            foreach (string item in l.Items)
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }

            return list.ToString();
        }
```

but im obviously missing the newline split which i am struggling with.
The current code only saves "System.Collections.ArrayList" into the database.

I also did alot of googling and keep coming across "string[]" but thats no good as i have to predefine the length, which i dont know as it keeps changing when items get added to the ListView.

I also need a reverse method when reading the values from the database to put each line back into the ListView.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StringBuilder perfectly saves the CR/LF chars.

```
  public string ConvertToString(ListView l)
  {
     StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();

     foreach (string item in l.Items)
        list.AppendLine(item);

     return list.ToString();
  }
```

Reverse is similar:

```
  public voidConvertToString(ListView l, string dbString)
  {
     string [] sep = {"\r\n"};
     foreach (string item in dbString.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None))
        l.Items.Add(item);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to save it correctly. But what can i use to do the reverse split, so i can assign each seperate string to the the ListView as ListViewItem

Comment: Thanks, all working a treat now. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this function to convert to an array of String:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a ListView to an array of string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ListView1"></param>
        /// <returns>an array of strings</returns>
        private string[] ConvertToArray(ListView ListView1)
        {
            string[] array = new string[ListView1.Items.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                array[i] = ListView1.Items[i].Text;
            }
            return array;
        }
```

The reverse solution could be similar.